# linux + ssh limitation + ssh at the same time from multiple machine to one machine

Tags: linux, performance, shell, ssh, expect

the following script "testssh.ksh" proves that ssh have some problems when we try to perform ssh from multiple machines on the same time

in fact the target of this script is to verify the file test_file under /var/tmp in the Solaris server (10.10.18.6) , as all see in some ssh steps we can’t  verify
the existing of the test_file because ssh stuck or not activate from the expect

background - this script perform 15 times ssh to Solaris server with IP - 10.10.18.6  on the same time in order to verify the file_test under /var/tmp in the server

my question - how to improve the ssh process in order to avoid the following problems

Remark - sleep can help us in this situation - but I not want to add sleep before ssh process

```
  [root@linux /var/tmp]# more  testssh.ksh
  #!/bin/ksh



  expect=`cat << EOF
  set timeout -1
  spawn  ssh  10.10.18.6 
       expect {
                 ")?"   { send "yes\r"  ; exp_continue  }

                 word:  {send pass123\r}
              }
  expect >  {send "ls  /var/tmp/test_file\r"}
  expect >    {send exit\r}
  expect eof
  EOF`


  for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
  do
     ( expect -c  "$expect"  | grep "test_file"  | grep -v ls ) &
  done
```

example - when we run the script testssh.ksh

```
     [root@linux /var/tmp]# /var/tmp/testssh.ksh
     /var/tmp/test_file
     /var/tmp/test_file
     /var/tmp/test_file
     /var/tmp/test_file
     /var/tmp/test_file
     expect: spawn id exp6 not open
     while executing
     "expect >  {send "ls  /var/tmp/test_file\r"}"
     expect: spawn id exp6 not open
     while executing
     "expect >  {send "ls  /var/tmp/test_file\r"}"
     expect: spawn id exp6 not open
     while executing
     "expect >  {send "ls  /var/tmp/test_file\r"}"
     expect: spawn id exp6 not open
     while executing
     "expect >  {send "ls  /var/tmp/test_file\r"}"
     /var/tmp/test_file
     /var/tmp/test_file
     /var/tmp/test_file
     /var/tmp/test_file
     /var/tmp/test_file
     /var/tmp/test_file
```

Comment: FYI, if you want to run a single command you can do `ssh 10.10.18.6 ls /var/tmp/test_file`. Anyway, yes, `sshd` can't handle 15 simultaneous logins on my Linux system either. That seems like a very high load for ssh. Maybe you should consider keeping connections open or using a different communication mechanism or just retrying the `ssh` command some number of times.

Comment: hi perelman please give me real example for "keeping connections open or using a different communication mechanism" --- just note I have more than 40 linux machines , and I need to perform ssh from all linux machines to one server on the same time

Comment: You just gave your test script, so I am unclear what your actual goal is. If it is to check for the existence of a file on a central server at some regular interval, then something like `ssh 10.10.18.6 sh -c "'while true; do ls /var/tmp/test_file; sleep 1m; done'" | while read current; do (react to line $current) done` might work.

Comment: the current goal is to verify from each machine and on the same time (using crontab ) the existing test_file that located in the central server , as I said I not want to use sleep command I have more than 40 linux machines and they triggered the ssh exactly at 12:00 PM

Comment: The code I gave has all 40 computers stay logged in and run `sleep` on the server. If your server cannot handle so many connections exactly at once, the reasonable solution seems to be some scheme to connect at different times so all the clients already have open connections by 12:00pm to run their command on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you set the `MaxSession` and `MaxStartups` in your `sshd.conf` (or equivalent)? 40 simultaneous SSH connections should not, I believe, be too many for your server to handle.

From `man sshd_config` page:

```
 MaxSessions
         Specifies the maximum number of open sessions permitted per net‐
         work connection.  The default is 10.

 MaxStartups
         Specifies the maximum number of concurrent unauthenticated con‐
         nections to the SSH daemon.  Additional connections will be
         dropped until authentication succeeds or the LoginGraceTime
         expires for a connection.  The default is 10.

         Alternatively, random early drop can be enabled by specifying the
         three colon separated values “start:rate:full” (e.g. "10:30:60").
         sshd(8) will refuse connection attempts with a probability of
         “rate/100” (30%) if there are currently “start” (10) unauthenti‐
         cated connections.  The probability increases linearly and all
         connection attempts are refused if the number of unauthenticated
         connections reaches “full” (60).
```

If you haven't changed these, your server won't handle more than 10 simultaneous connections.

[Similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/134367/ssh-port-forwarding-freezes-after-10-simultaneous-connections) (serverfault.com).

Comment: The explanation is talking about number of **sessions** per connection. And the question is about number of **connections**.